# Error during installing requirements.txt in Django (metadata generation failed)

Tags: python, django, requirements.txt

I tried installing requirements.txt in Django. Virtual env is activated.
This error is showing after I tried pip install -r requirements.txt

[image]

After that I also tried to migrate but still not working.

*This is github fork I downloaded, it has a pickle file as well as its based on ML model.*

Here is the requirements.txt

```
asgiref==3.3.4
click==7.1.2
Django==2.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
joblib==1.0.1
nltk==3.6.2
numpy==1.20.2
pandas==1.2.4
psycopg2==2.8.6
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2021.1
regex==2021.4.4
scikit-learn==0.24.2
scipy==1.6.3
six==1.15.0
sklearn==0.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
threadpoolctl==2.1.0
tqdm==4.60.0
typing-extensions==3.10.0.0
whitenoise==5.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have shared the requirements.txt file. Otherwise, try installing django via `pip install -U django`

Comment: I can but what about other dependencies?

Comment: Open your requirements.txt file in vscode and change == to >= and then pip install it.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to a newer version of `numpy`. That particular version does not have a prebuilt wheel for your version of Python, and trying to build from source is evidently failing.

I.e. change `numpy==1.20.2` to e.g. `numpy==1.23.0` and try again.

Comment: I tried this and it was success. But for scikit_learn, it again failed. Do you know which version I should install

Comment: You can just try getting rid of the version specifier altogether, so the latest version is installed.